# Juggling with pointer-to-member-functions within class declaration

Tags: c++, class, arduino, function-pointers

I am trying to have a member function redirect itself to other member functions on-the-fly. Here is some boiled-down pseudo-code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
            Foo();

            int counter = 0;

            void slaveA() { counter++; };
            void slaveB() { counter--; };

            void (*master)() = &slaveA;

            void toggleSlave()
            {
                _useB = !_useB;

                if (_useB)
                    master = &slaveB;
                else
                    master = &slaveA;
            }

    private:
            boolean _useB = false;
}; 


Foo foo;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    if (random(2) == 0)
        foo.toggleSlave();

    foo.master();
    Serial.println(foo.counter);
    delay(500);
}
```

However, I keep running into these errors no matter what I do:

```
cannot convert 'void (Foo::*)()' to 'void (*)()' in initialization
cannot convert 'void (Foo::*)()' to 'void (*)()' in assignment
```

In my main project, the equivalent of `master` will be called as fast as the hardware can permit with at least 5 slaves, which is why I'm trying to toggle between function pointers rather than placing an if-else inside `master`.

I've read a bunch of stuff that says static functions would be the preferred approach, but I need the slave methods to be able to manipulate member variables, and ideally I want everything to be contained within the class declaration so technically the object reference is readily available to all member functions involved.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the slaves are non-static member functions, `master` needs to be a pointer to a member function and not a pointer to a function. The code would look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
            Foo();

            int counter = 0;

            void slaveA() { counter++; };
            void slaveB() { counter--; };

            void (Foo::*master)() = &Foo::slaveA;

            void toggleSlave()
            {
                _useB = !_useB;

                if (_useB)
                    master = &Foo::slaveB;
                else
                    master = &Foo::slaveA;
            }

    private:
            bool _useB = false;
};

void loop()
{
    if (random(2) == 0)
        foo.toggleSlave();

    (foo.*foo.master)();
    Serial.println(foo.counter);
    delay(500);
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78ea4e624f9ad819)

Since the syntax `(foo.*foo.master)()` is rather ugly, I suggest making `master` a function in `foo` and the member pointer its implementation detail:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
            Foo();

            int counter = 0;

            void slaveA() { counter++; };
            void slaveB() { counter--; };

            void master() {
              (this->*_master)();
            }

            void toggleSlave()
            {
                _useB = !_useB;

                if (_useB)
                    _master = &Foo::slaveB;
                else
                    _master = &Foo::slaveA;
            }

    private:
            void (Foo::*_master)() = &Foo::slaveA;
            bool _useB = false;
};

void loop()
{
    if (random(2) == 0)
        foo.toggleSlave();

    foo.master();
    Serial.println(foo.counter);
    delay(500);
}
```